# URL resolution in Django with two patterns

Tags: python, django, regex, url, django-urls

There is a need to provide options to task and subtask in Django. where example task is `abc_123` ,example subtask is `xyz-987`

```
example.com/abc_123/options
example.com/abc_123/xyz-987/options
```

My urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/(?P<taskId>.+)/options$', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
    url(r'^/(?P<taskId>.+)/(?P<subtaskId>.+)/options$', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
]
```

It is working fine when only taskId is sent. When both task and subtaskId is sent. The pattern is taking `abc_123/xyz-987` as taskId. I need url to be resolved as `abc_123` and `xyz-987` as taskId and subtaskId respectively

Comment: Change `r'^/(?P<taskId>.+)/options$'` to `r'^/(?P<taskId>[^/]+)/options$'`. Actually, `r'^/(?P<taskId>.+)/(?P<subtaskId>.+)/options$'` is also better changed to `r'^/(?P<taskId>[^/]+)/(?P<subtaskId>[^/]+)/options$'`

Comment: Changing the url worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not match the slash, so we can work with a character group that matches all except the slash, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/(?P<taskId>[^/]+)/options$', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
    url(r'^/(?P<taskId>[^/]+)/(?P<subtaskId>[^/]+)/options$', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
]
```

You might however want to use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) with the `<str:…>` path converter, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:taskId>/options/', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
    path('<str:taskId>/<str:subpathId>/options/', views.AvailableOptions.as_view()),
]
```